# UK visa says it's been issued for a family visit, can I still use it for a vacation?

Tags: visas, uk

My dad has a 10 year UK visa, on the remarks it says "family visit"
my question is if we go on a vacation to the UK will it be a problem for him ? can they refuse him entry?

Comment: Could you upload a scan of your visa?

Comment: when you scan visa remove name and visa number

Comment: In general UK like US and some few other countries, visa is not a guaranty for accessing the country. the police can always deny you access. Question if that is legal or not I really do not know.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ surely it is true for all countries that a visa is no guarantee of entry, not "some few."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On 24 April 2015 all existing visitor visas, including family visitor, business visitor, student visitor, child visitor, and others were automatically converted to the 'standard visitor visa'.

So yes, your father can go on a vaction to the UK or do any of the other activities listed in Appendix 3 (Permitted Activities) in [Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) of the rules.

The controlling link if you are interested is the [Immigration Act 2014](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2014/22/enacted).