# Is it OK to use UK Visitor Visa for multiple entries with different reasons

Tags: uk

My girlfriend had applied a standard visitor visa last year and her stated reason was tourism. Is it OK for her to visit me now, as it's now for a different reason?

Comment: what is the reason now? It could continue to be tourism. She is not going to work or stay in the country...

Comment: Were you her boyfriend at the time of the Visa application? if so was she honest about it?

Comment: @PeterGreen  Thanks for your reply! I was her boyfriend at the time. She didn't state she wanted to visit me because at that time her college arranged a trip to UK. I wasn't in UK at that time yet.

Comment: @MarcelP. The reason I want to check this is because she might end up applying for the Tier  dependant visa in the future (I'm current holding Tier 2 working visa in UK).

Comment: Is it a multiple entry visa she already used once last year and now wants to use again for another visit, or a single entry visa she applied for with one reason but now wants to use for something else?

Comment: @ZachLipton It's a multiple entry visa now want to be used again for another visit.

Answer (score 2):

With a Standard Visitor Visa, she can come and go and do any activity listed in [Appendix 3 of the Immigration Rules Appendix V visitor rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules). This holds true even if the stated purpose on the application now differs from the current purpose. Among them, you'll see

> **Tourism and leisure**
>   3 A visitor may visit friends and family and / or come to the UK for a holiday.

Of particular relevance, as this question is frequently asked on this site, [@GayotFow explained that](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69041/uk-visa-says-its-been-issued-for-a-family-visit-can-i-still-use-it-for-a-vacat/69051#69051):

> On 24 April 2015 all existing visitor visas, including family visitor, business visitor, student visitor, child visitor, and others were automatically converted to the 'standard visitor visa'.
>
> [ ]
>   The controlling link if you are interested is the [Immigration Act 2014](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2014/22/enacted).

For additional reference: [Can I travel to the UK for business on a C visit visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88433/can-i-travel-to-the-uk-for-business-on-a-c-visit-visa/88437#88437)